# How to speed up matplotlib scatter ploting?

Tags: performance, matplotlib

I need to draw a batch of scatter charts in matplotlib, and found the speed of matplotlib is slow, then I lineprofile the function, and found the hotspot is `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, It costs 56.1% of time to creat a blank figure and axes !!

How to speed it up ? I mean, how can I reuse fig and ax to avoid creating them each time ?

Attach the profile report here (I cut some of the line to make it simple)

```
Total time: 0.733771 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   517                                           @profile
   518                                           def df_scatter(df):
   519                                               ''' draw the scatter plot for Pandas dataframe 'df'
   533                                               '''                   
   536                                           
   537         1           75     75.0      0.0      biggest_area = 1000
   538         1          117    117.0      0.0      mycm =  matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('jet') # 'spectral'
   539                                           
   541         1           78     78.0      0.0      col_qty = len(df.columns)
   543                                           
   544         1         1859   1859.0      0.1      x = list(df.ix[:,0].values)
   545         1         1258   1258.0      0.0      y = list(df.ix[:,1].values)                                      
   551                                               
   552         1      1472345 1472345.0     56.1     fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   556                                               
   557         1         7007   7007.0      0.3      plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.07, right=0.92, bottom=0.1, top=0.95)
   558         1          179    179.0      0.0      x_margin, y_margin = (max(x)-min(x))/20, (max(y)-min(y))/20
   563                                           
   564         1           71     71.0      0.0      if col_qty > 2:
   565         1         1602   1602.0      0.1          r = list(df.ix[:,2].values)
   566         1          309    309.0      0.0          size_r = np.array(biggest_area)*r/max(r)
   585                                           
   586         1        34712  34712.0      1.3          sc = plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=size_r, cmap=mycm, alpha=0.65)
   587                                           
   588                                                   # adding colorbar
   589         1       542417 542417.0     20.7          cbaxes = fig.add_axes([0.94, 0.25, 0.02, 0.70])
   590         1       165719 165719.0      6.3          cbar = plt.colorbar(sc, cax=cbaxes)
   591         1          122    122.0      0.0          cbar.solids.set_edgecolor('face')
   595                                           
   602         1         1061   1061.0      0.0          plt.figtext(0.94,0.10,"%0.1f"%(max(r)), fontproperties=TEXT_FONT_MEDIUM)
   639         1           66     66.0      0.0      return fig
```

Comment: keep track of all the artists you add and then `.remove()` them when you are done.  You can also probably re-use the axes you create for the color bar.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the best way to do it is calling

```
fig = plt.figure() 
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
```

from outside of df_scatter. Then, pass it to df_scatter as arguments:

```
df_scatter(df,fig,ax):
```

or simply do inside df_scatter:

```
def df_scatter(df):
    fig = plt.gcf()
    ax = plt.gca()
```

after the creation of fig & axis was done.

Comment: Not work, for it will overlap the content of fig when reuse it. And fig.clf() also cost lots of time.